# Visual Studio 2010, remote debugging and AD not co-operating, what's wrong?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, active-directory, remote-debugging

I'm remote debugging a console app which has some AD functionality.

When I run it on the remote server it works like a charm. (I mean I log in with RDC and literally double click the console app .exe file.)

While remote debugging however, I'm getting an error in the AD related code - "Could not find the domain or the domain does not exist".

Important to note is my dev machine is not on the same domain as remote server. I'm also remote debugging over VPN.

I also want to mention that otherwise the remote debugging seems to be working ok, breakpoints are being met, symbols loading, values populating.

The full source code is kinda long, so I'll just provide an illustation of what is causing the problem:

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry dirEntry; // in reality this is setup via an ad helper class
dirEntry.rootOU.Children.Find(strOU, "Something"); // BOOM! here is where it can't find the domain
```

Its not a code issue, and the domain does genuinely exist and is reachable, when code is natively executed on the server, issue only comes in with remote debugging.

Thanks in advance for suggestions on a fix / cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of struggling, I found the problem but no solution.

The solution is to have your environments setup in best case scenario if you want to remote debug in an SOA application, connecting to many systems using domain accounts etc.

Your local dev environment should be running under the same domain and account as the account running the remote services on the server. Furthermore, this account needs to have correct permissions in your SOA systems. I.E: If you're working with AD, this account needs to have required permissions. If you're working with Sharepoint, you might need to use the farm admin account. SQL or Databases are much more forgiving because you can configure connection strings.

If you fail to do any of the above, remote debugging can still work for you but it might not. If it does not, what I've found is there is no work around.

You might think you would be able to use No authentication remote debugging, but that does not work with managed code. So (Jan 28th 2010) no solution exists.

I hope this is addressed in the future, because it can be extremely convenient debug remotely.